# Inno Setup: Verify that {app} path contains no spaces

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to check the target installation directory path for spaces?
If it contains a space, a message should come up and installation shouldn't be possible.

I know, spaces shouldn't be a problem for any tool, but we are using some older tools which won't run when there are spaces in the path and it would be too much effort to change this behavior.

Another solution: The user can just choose the drive letter. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***How to check if the selected directory contains a space in name and if so, display a message box and disallow setup wizard to continue?***

The following script checks for a space in the selected directory and if that directory contains a space, it shows a message box and keeps the user on the directory selection page. This is performed when the user is going to leave the directory selection page by clicking the *Next* button:

```pascal
[Code]

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  { if we're on the directory selection page and the value returned by }
  { the WizardDirValue function contains at least one space, then... }
  if (CurPageID = wpSelectDir) and (Pos(' ', WizardDirValue) > 0) then
  begin
    Result := False;
    MsgBox('Target installation directory cannot contain spaces. ' +
      'Choose a different one.', mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```